# MySql SQL_NO_CACHE Issue Between 5.0 And 5.5

Tags: mysql

The following query works in MySql 5.0

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
    ItemId,
    AnotherColumn
FROM
    TableOne
UNION
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
    ItemId,
    AnotherColumn
FROM
    TableTwo
```

But in MySql 5.5 I get the following error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException:
>   Incorrect usage/placement of
>   'SQL_NO_CACHE'

What is the correct placement of SQL_NO_CACHE for UNION queries?

If I put SQL_NO_CACHE on one side of the UNION, will it affect both sides?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of MySql 5.5.3, you just need to specify SQL_NO_CACHE in the first SELECT of a UNION query:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
    ItemId,
    AnotherColumn
FROM
    TableOne
UNION
SELECT
    ItemId,
    AnotherColumn
FROM
    TableTwo
```

It applies to the whole query. If you try and specify it in the subsequent SELECT statements it will error (and it is also now allowed in sub-queries).